# jquery toggling a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checked

I've been at this for the past 2 hours and cannot get this figured out.

I have a list item that when clicked the jquery pulls the class of the li item which is a color. It then Capitalizes the first letter then finds the checkbox value with the color matching and marks it as checked.

Only I want it so that if someone clicks the li item again it will uncheck the checkbox

Can someone help at all?

```
$('#colours li').live('click', function (){
    var color = $(this).attr('class');
    color = color[0].toUpperCase() + color.slice(1);
    console.log($('input[value="'+color+'"]'));
    $(this).css('opacity','0.5');

    if($('input[value="'+color+'"]:checked').length) {
        $('input[value="'+color+'"]').attr('checked', true);
        console.log("checked");
    } else {
        $('input[value="'+color+'"]').removeAttr('checked');
        console.log("not checked");
    }    
});



<ul id="colours">
        <li class="black"></li>
        <li class="brown"></li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Black" class="hidden" />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Brown" class="hidden" />
```

forgot to add the ul and inputs are loaded using jquery .load()

Comment: @Ohgodwhy's solution works. Just swap around his `.prop('checked', true/false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do

```
$('#colours').on('click', 'li', function (){
  var th = $(this);
  var color = th.attr('class');
  color = color[0].toUpperCase() + color.slice(1);
  var input = $('input[value="'+color+'"]')
  console.log(input);
  th.css('opacity','0.5');

  if(input.length == 1) {
    if (input.is(':checked')) {
      input.prop('checked', false);  
      console.log("not checked");
    } else {
      input.prop('checked', true); 
      console.log("checked");
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Or if you already know that there is exactly one element, `input[0].checked = !input[0].checked;`

Comment: Used this method but swapped .on for .live and .prop for .attr

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the attribute, you're taking it out of the DOM, literally. You just want to toggle the checked property. Some changes to note.

`.live()` is deprecated; I've replaced it with the proper `.on()` call.

`.attr()` is deprecated in *almost* all cases, in favor of `.prop()`. I've replaced this as well.

We don't need to check the length, we need to check if the element is checked. jQuery provides an `.is()` with a `psuedo-selector` of `:checked`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#colours li',  function() {
    var color = $(this).prop('class');
    color = color[0].toUpperCase() + color.slice(1);
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');

    $('input[value="' + color + '"]').prop('checked', function(i,oldVal){
        return !oldVal;
    });

});​
```

Comment: Since you're upgrading the JS, you should store `$(this)` as well as the input selector.

Comment: You need to swap around the `.prop('checked', true/false)`.

Comment: @Petr Marek - Howdy bud, I would normally cache the variable, but we call the object only two times. There's no performance gain there that's substantial enough to warrant a variable declaration. Have a nice day!

Comment: `$('input[value="' + color + '"]').prop('checked', function(i,oldVal){return !oldVal;});` is another option.

Comment: @nnnnnn Totally right, that's actually a very *very* good point, thank you nnnnnn.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `if` statement at all if you use the `!oldVal` method...

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks -- shortsightedness today